# How to make proxy server

Tags: java, server, proxy, specifications

I want to make proxy server to modify my request body, header before forward to real server.

I can just image, how to work in http proxy.

However, I want to know exactly how to work socket proxy, `https proxy` and `http proxy`.

I want to read official proxy server specification, but I cannot find it.

Could you explain where can I find the proxy spec?

Comment: List, what you have done so far, what your environment is. 
Since this is no real development question you should maybe look at the superuser site https://superuser.com/

Comment: I just want to ask theoretical question. Does stack overflow's users always want to see code?

Comment: yes. It shows,what you have done so far yourself to solve your problem. Either post code or links to sources you already have tried out.
It is just polite to put some effort in yourself before you are asking other for their time to help you.